# Unity falha ao carregar biblioteca Vuforia

Tags: unity3d, vuforia

Galera, tô com um problema com o Unity 5 e o Vuforia 4. Estou tentando rodar o exemplo que encontrei [aqui](https://noperation.wordpress.com/2014/11/09/realidade-aumentada-com-vuforia-em-unity3d-instalacao-e-exemplo-ola-mundo/).

Todas as vezes que tento rodar o teste ele lança os seguintes erros:

Erro 1:

```
Failed to load 'Assets/Plugins/QCARWrapper.dll', expected 64 bit architecture (IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64), but was IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386.
Vuforia.WebCamAbstractBehaviour:IsWebCamUsed()
Vuforia.WebCamAbstractBehaviour:IsWebCamUsed()
Vuforia.VuforiaRuntimeUtilities:IsVuforiaEnabled()
Vuforia.TurnOffBehaviour:Awake() (at Assets/Vuforia/Scripts/TurnOffBehaviour.cs:21)
```

Erro 2:

```
Failed to load 'Assets/Plugins/QCARWrapper.dll', expected 64 bit architecture (IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64), but was IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386.
Vuforia.WebCamAbstractBehaviour:CheckNativePluginSupport()
Vuforia.WebCamAbstractBehaviour:CheckNativePluginSupport()
Vuforia.WebCamAbstractBehaviour:IsWebCamUsed()
Vuforia.VuforiaRuntimeUtilities:IsVuforiaEnabled()
Vuforia.TurnOffBehaviour:Awake() (at Assets/Vuforia/Scripts/TurnOffBehaviour.cs:21)
```

Alguém pode me dar uma luz? Grato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "expected 64 bit architecture"

Tive o mesmo problema tentando com o Unity na versão 64 bits.
Aparentemente há um conflito (32x64 bits).

Ainda, sobre as versões recomendadas e compatíveis. 
De acordo com o site do Vuforia:

> "Note: Vuforia 5 is compatible with the following: Unity versions `5.1.3p1` and `4.6.7`.
>   Unity `5.1.3p1` resolves performance issues experienced with earlier 5.x releases"

Portanto, sugiro que instale:

- A versão **5.1.3p1** da Unity (32 bits) - [**Acesse Aqui**](https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/patch-releases?version=5.1)
- Em conjunto com a versão mais estável e recente do SDK - [**Acesse Aqui**](https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/sdk)

É um erro muito recorrente de acordo com o fórum e essas duas versões funcionam perfeitamente aqui depois de muita dor de cabeça.

Boa sorte!